# Creating the proper suction

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vacuum

I'm a bit rusty on my fluid dynamics.  I'm experimenting with creating my own leaf vacuum.

How would I determine how much suction a fan creates?
Bernoulli's equation would apply correct?
I would also need a fan curve right?
Does CFM matter much when creating a vacuum?

Ultimately what I'm looking for is the Force @ inlet (P x Ainlet) > Force on leaves (m x g)...?

Comment: vacuum.... as in vacuum cleaner?

Comment: Pretty much yeah.